# Detecting when a button is clicked? [C++, WinAPI]

Tags: c++, winapi, button, onclick, click

Okay so in this program, I am using Code::Blocks IDE and GNU GCC compiler to compile an executable. It is a Win32 GUI project. My problem is that although it was all working, I recently tried to implement clicking of the buttons to code them & make them work. However, I'm getting a strange error, because the guy told me the code should work/

> Error: ||=== Build file: Release in Agsploit (compiler: GNU GCC
>   Compiler) ===| C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Agsploit\main.cpp||In function 'int
>   WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)':|
>   C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Agsploit\main.cpp|14|error: expected
>   unqualified-id before numeric constant|
>   C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Agsploit\main.cpp|55|note: in expansion of macro
>   'Execute'| ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s),
>   1 second(s)) ===|

Code (Sorry, not sure how to format it here, so pastebin'd it):
http://pastebin.com/raw/r6b5NcXK

```
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
    #define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
    #define UNICODE
#endif

#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

TCHAR szClassName[] = _T("WindowClass");

#define Execute 0
#define RunScript 1
#define Clear 2
#define Help 3
#define Credits 4
#define Commands 5
#define Exit 6

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow) {
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG messages;
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl)) {
        return 0;
    };
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
           0,
           szClassName,
           _T("LightNinG  || v1  || By: [Team AzuL]"),
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW ^ WS_THICKFRAME,
           400,
           200,
           740,
           390,
           HWND_DESKTOP,
           NULL,
           hThisInstance,
           NULL
    );
    HWND Execute = CreateWindow(
        "BUTTON",
        "Execute",
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
        250,
        315,
        235,
        50,
        hwnd,
        (HMENU)Execute,
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
        NULL
    );
    HWND ScriptButton = CreateWindow(
        "BUTTON",
        "Run script",
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
        485,
        315,
        250,
        50,
        hwnd,
        (HMENU)RunScript,
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
        NULL
    );
    HWND Clear = CreateWindow(
        "BUTTON",
        "Clear",
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
        0,
        315,
        250,
        50,
        hwnd,
        (HMENU)Clear,
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
        NULL
    );
    HWND Help = CreateWindow(
        "BUTTON",
        "Help",
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
        400,
        0,
        85,
        84,
        hwnd,
        (HMENU)Help,
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
        NULL
    );
    HWND Credits = CreateWindow(
        "BUTTON",
        "Credits",
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
        400,
        84,
        85,
        84,
        hwnd,
        (HMENU)Credits,
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
        NULL
    );
    HWND Commands = CreateWindow(
        "BUTTON",
        "Commands",
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
        400,
        168,
        85,
        84,
        hwnd,
        (HMENU)Commands,
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
        NULL
    );
    HWND Exit = CreateWindow(
        "BUTTON",
        "Exit",
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
        400,
        252,
        85,
        64,
        hwnd,
        (HMENU)Exit,
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
        NULL
    );
    HWND OutputWindow = CreateWindow("Edit", "Hello, and welcome to LightNinG by Team AzuL.\r\nCurrent version: 1\r\nCurrent # of commands: 0", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_READONLY, 0, 0, 400, 290, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    HWND InputBar = CreateWindow("Edit", "Input commands here.", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 0, 290, 400, 25, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    HWND ScriptBox = CreateWindow("Edit", "Script(s) go here {client-sided}.", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE, 485, 0, 250, 314, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);
    while (GetMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    };
    return messages.wParam;
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
   switch (message) {
       case WM_COMMAND:
           switch(LOWORD(wParam)) {
               case Execute:

               break;
               case RunScript:

               break;
               case Clear:

               break;
               case Help:

               break;
               case Credits:
                   MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"Created by team AzuL.", (LPCWSTR)L"Credits", MB_OK);
               break;
               case Commands:

               break;
               case Exit:

               break;
            }
        break;
       case WM_DESTROY:
           PostQuitMessage(0);
           break;
       default:
           return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
   };
   return 0;
};
```

Comment: Thanks mah, can you tell me how you did that?

Comment: I pasted the code in, selected it all, and pressed control-K. This is a shortcut that just adds 4 spaces at the beginning of each line.

Comment: Ah thanks, the reason I didn't format it is because I wasn't aware of how to do it all at once. It would have taken a while.

Comment: If I may ask one more thing, how do I make an HWND variable accessable outside of the function I defined it in?

Comment: You need to ask that as a separate question please.  Hint: Return it.

Comment: @LeviBranch You really shouldn't be using the preprocessor this way.   Not only is it a reason for your errors, defining common words such as `Help` and `Exit` may interfere with previous definitions, functions, etc. used in a header file.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is a standalone program, it uses no header files that I have made and the way that the program this is used in (nested .exe's hehe) there would be no interference that I can percieve. However I will take that into account. And uh, I do need to make it a global variable here, on this thread. I cant post again :/

Comment: @LeviBranch No header files?  So what is `<tchar.h>` and `<windows.h>`?   You don't know what these headers may contain either now or in the future.  And as my other comment suggested, I had to fix a problem just like this, where the person used `#define FILE 1`.  Guess what?  `FILE` is used in `<cstdio>`.  Even if the program is standalone, that doesn't make it ok to introduce bad habits into it.

Comment: @LeviBranch My point is that it is never a good idea to use common names for macros.  That's why libraries like `boost` use `BOOST_xxx` for macro names, making sure that there is no possibility of a name clash at compile time, or worse, the program builds but has runtime issues.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie well okay but I cant post a thread to ask this.. so assuming I have the pointer Boxes::KInputBar how do I get ALL of the text inside it? It's a TextBox btw.

Comment: @LeviBranch - `WM_GETTEXT`, `GetWindowText`.

Answer (score 2):

Line 14 (pointed out in your error message) is

```
#define Execute 0
```

Line 55 (also pointed out in your error message) is:

```
    HWND Execute = CreateWindow(
```

Which gets expanded to:

```
    HWND 0 = CreateWindow(
```

... which is not valid C++.

There is a reason that experts strongly advise:

1. Use the preprocessor as little as possible.
2. If you must use it, use ALL_UPPER_CASE for macros (and for nothing else).

The preferred solution would be something like:

```
enum class Command : int
{
    Execute = 1,  // I'd always reserve 0 for "no such command".
    RunScript,
    Clear,
    Help,
    Credits,
    Commands,
    Exit,
};
```

and then you can create the button with `(HMENU)Command::Execute`.

Comment: Hmm.. so that means that I need to define them differently at the top? Such as DEFINED_EXE instead of Execute?

Comment: Even using all upper case can get you in trouble.  I have had the misfortune of debugging code that had `#define FILE 1` in it.  The problem of course is that `FILE` is used in `<cstdio>`.

Comment: My solution is to put Z_VARIABLE because Z_ should not be used by windows (if it was eww).